# Scrapy - Continuously fetch urls to crawl from database

Tags: python, database, loops, scrapy

I'd like to continuously fetch urls to crawl from a database. So far I succeeded in fetching urls from the base but I'd like my spider to keep reading from that base since the table will be populated by another thread.

I have a pipeline that removes url from the table once it is crawled (working). In other words, I'd like to use my database as a queue. I tried different approaches with no luck.

Here's my spider.py

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  MAX_RETRY = 10
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

  name = 'myspider'
  start_urls = [
      ]

  @classmethod
  def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
      spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
      crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
      return spider

  def __init__(self):
      db = MySQLdb.connect(
          user='myuser',
          passwd='mypassword',
          db='mydatabase',
          host='myhost',
          charset='utf8',
          use_unicode=True
          )
      self.db = db
      self.logger.info('Connection to database opened')
      super(MySpider, self)

  def spider_closed(self, spider):
      self.db.close()
      self.logger.info('Connection to database closed')


  def start_requests(self):
      cursor = self.db.cursor()
      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < %s', (self.MAX_RETRY,))
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
          yield Request(row[0], self.parse, meta={
              'splash': {
                  'args':{
                      'html': 1,
                      'wait': 2
                      }
                  }
              }, errback=self.errback_httpbin)
      cursor.close()
```

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

Here's my new code.

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
    return spider

def spider_idle(self, spider):
    self.logger.info('IDLE')
    time.sleep(5)
        for url in self.getUrlsToCrawl():
            self.logger.info(url[1])
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(Request(url[1], self.parse, meta={
               'splash': {
                   'args':{
                       'html': 1,
                       'wait': 5
                       }
                   },
                'dbId': url[0]
               }, errback=self.errback_httpbin), self)
    raise DontCloseSpider       

def getUrlsToCrawl(self):
    dateNowUtc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id, url FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < %s AND domain = %s and nextCrawl < %s', (self.MAX_RETRY, self.domain, dateNowUtc))
    urls = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return urls
```

In my logs I can see :
INFO: IDLE
INFO: someurl
INFO: IDLE
INFO: someurl

But when I update the data in my table to fetch more or less urls, the output never changes. It seems that the data collected is not fresh and I never crawl the requests made in the spider_idle method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would personally recommend to start a new spider every time you have to crawl something but if you want to keep the process alive I would recommend using the [`spider_idle`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle) signal:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)
    return spider
...
def spider_idle(self, spider):
    # read database again and send new requests

    # check that sending new requests here is different
    self.crawler.engine.crawl(
                    Request(
                        new_url,
                        callback=self.parse),
                    spider
                )
```

Here you are sending new requests before the spider actually closes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'd like to keep it alive because I want to crawl in real time, I could use a cron but if my spider takes longer than the period, the tasks are going to stack and can lead to bad behavior. It seems that you are showing me the right direction but my spider is closing after going once into my idle method. Any idea ?

Comment: I added `raise DontCloseSpider` and the end of `my spider_idle` and my spider is now running for ever. 

However it seems that it only read url from the database once but I can see my logger keeping saying "i'm alive".

Comment: I can't help you on something I don't see, could you update your code?

Comment: where is the `"I'm alive"` log?

Comment: `self.logger.info('IDLE')` I reckon it's not actually I'm alive, sorry ^^ Before I added `raise DontCloseSpider` I could only see one "IDLE" in the log, now my spider is always alive

Comment: please check my code again, you are missing the `Request` part in the `spider_idle` method

Comment: Sorry I failed my copy and past, the request is there otherwise the spider won't be running, I edited my question again

Comment: share your complete logs, maybe duplicated requests are being filtered? use the `dont_filter=True` Request argument if that is the case.

Comment: `dont_filter=True` was indeed missing and the method that get the url had a problem, `self.db.commit()` was missing so I was getting the same result every time. It is working now thank you very much!