# Create new request for Scrapy schedule

Tags: python, scrapy, rabbitmq, pika

Via pika i take url from rabbitmq and try to create new request for Scrapy spider
When i start my spider by `scrapy crawl spider` spider just don't close due to `raise DontCloseSpider()` but don't create a request for spider
My custom exception:

```
import pika
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider


class AddRequestExample:

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
        return s


    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        try:
            url = channel.basic_get(queue='hello')[2]
            url = url.decode()
            crawler.engine.crawl(Request(url), self)
        except Exception:
            pass
        raise DontCloseSpider()
```

my spider:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
        'url': response.url
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to reproduce approach from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41447672/10884791).

In this case you need to define request callback function.
 As you process `spider_idle` signal from extension (not from spider) - it should be `spider.parse` method.

```
def spider_idle(self, spider):
    ....
    try:
        url = channel.basic_get(queue='hello')[2]
        url = url.decode()
        spider.crawler.engine.crawl(Request(url=url, callback = spider.parse), self)
    except Exception:
    ....
```